# Swagger v3 default values for Request body do not work

Tags: java, swagger

I want different default values for my request, I don't want the ones that Swagger suggests.

Let's say I want this class to have some default values:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Example{
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

I did some research and tried this @Schema annotation, but unfortunately nothing changed:

```
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "test")
    @Operation(
            summary = "test",
            requestBody = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            content = @Content(
                    mediaType = "application/json",
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = Example.class, example = SwaggerConstants.EXAMPLE_DEFAULT_VALUES)
            )
    ))
    public Example uploadExample(
            @PathVariable("id") Long id,
            @RequestBody() Example example) {

        return exampleService.uploadExample(id, example);
    }
```

SwaggerConstants looks like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class SwaggerConstants {
    public static final String EXAMPLE_DEFAULT_VALUES =
            "{\n" +
                    "  \"id\": 0,\n" +
                    "  \"title\": \"Default Title\"\n" +
                    "}";
}
```